# Electron Load Lag in Renderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, process, electron

I am currently building an electron typescript react app. It is a sort of account manager, which can retreive data for the specific accounts and display the data to the user.

My Problem is, that the ipcMain.on('acc:reload') fetches from an api, then loads the data into an object and sends it to the renderer.

For the whole fetch time (or for multiple accounts 'fetch-times') the renderer window process is freezing.
I thought, that the main process is seperated and does not block the renderer therefore.

The relevant code:

listeners.ts (snippet)

```
ipcMain.on('acc:reload', async (event) => {
    event.reply('acc:reload', accounts); // old account data to at least display something
    try {
      const updatedAccounts = await Promise.all(
        accounts.map(async (acc) => {
          try {
            const newData = await getAccountData(acc);
            return { ...acc, data: newData };
          } catch (error) {
            console.error(
              `Error reloading data for account ${acc.username}:`,
              error
            );
            // If an error occurs, return the original account without data
            return acc;
          }
        })
      );
      writeAccountsToFile(updatedAccounts);
      event.reply('acc:reload', updatedAccounts); // new 'fetched' account data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error reloading account data:', error);
    }
  });
```

App.tsx

```
function Main() {
  const refreshAccounts = () => {
    window.electron.accountLoadHandler.sendMessage('acc:reload');
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    refreshAccounts();
  }, []);
  window.electron.accountLoadHandler.once('acc:reload', (accs: Account[]) => {
    setAccounts(accs);
  });

  return (
    <div className="px-4 dark:bg-zinc-900 h-full min-h-screen dark:text-zinc-300">
      <Header handleRefresh={refreshAccounts} switchDark={switchDark} />
      <AccountList accounts={accounts} />
      <ToastContainer />
      <div className="flex w-full p-2 justify-center">
        <p>2024 ©</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

account data fetcher:

```
export default async function getAccountData(acc: Account) {
  const url = `example.com/api/data` + account.name;
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const text = await response.text();
    const dom = new JSDOM(text);
    const flexData = await readFlexData(dom.window.document);
    const soloData = await readSoloData(dom.window.document);

    const data = {
      solo: soloData,
      flex: flexData,
    } as IData;
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Request failed ERROR:', err);
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

As said the fetch request is inside the main process.

Would it be good practice to, fetch inside the renderer -> send data to main -> modify, clean, writeToFile() -> send back to renderer?

In my mind, doing the fetch request there does not seem right, but could be the solution. Or should I work with some form of workerThread?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed my problem was using 'electron-fetch' module.

```
import fetch from 'electron-fetch';
```

That way it truly asynchronously loaded the content and did not block the process.